# Signalr onConnected

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, signalr

So i did this :

```
 public string  getClientConnectionId()
{
    return Context.ConnectionId;
}
```

i have a default.aspx page in server side i did this on page load

```
string i = new ChatHub().getClientConnectionId();
```

but i get an object reference not set to an instance of an object error i need to get my client connection id so i can store it in my database in my database the client have two id's the primary key id that is autogenerated and the ChatId who should be the connection Id so how can i fix my problem ?

Comment: I think it's a good idea to post a stack trace

Comment: it looks like `Context` is null, what is the question?

Comment: the question is why my context is null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using WebForms and you have an aspx page with a code behind, you can't do new MyPage().Page_Load(), it'll blow up in some way since you are **NOT** responsible for creating the page. It's the same for MVC controllers and SignalR hubs and persistent connections.

When you start connection client side, it runs through a full pipeline in order to get a connection id. This connection id is available to you on the client side (using $.connection.hub.id in this case) and if you want to pass that back to your page in some way then you need to make a request to the page passing in the connection id from the client.

You can also do the mapping in the hub itself when a client connects but that would require more knowledge of your application to know if it was even possible.

Comment: This connection id is available to you on the client side (using $.connection.hub.id in this case) i just did :  var chat = $.connection.chatHub; $.connection.hub.start();
            alert(chat.id); i got 'undefined' message

Comment: You don't get an id until the connection is started: 

var chat = $.connection.chatHub; $.connection.hub.start().done(function() { alert($.connection.hub.id); });

Comment: The id is on the connection, **NOT** the hub instance hence ($.connection.hub.id)